# Comma between 'fellow' and organization's name

Tags: phrase-meaning, commas

I'm translating an article from English to my native language, and there are authors of article:
"Sinno Jialin Pan and Qiang Yang *Fellow, IEEE*"
IEEE is name of organisation, I assume that one of them is member of IEEE, but this comma bothers me, why is it there? Is it normal way to write this? Or does it change its meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation *Fellow, IEEE* is perfectly okay. In professional settings, a list of an individual's affiliations is typically in this order: *Title, Organization*. For example, this [course description at Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) lists the instructor's credentials as follows:

> Andrew Ng, Associate Professor, Stanford University; Chief Scientist, Baidu; Chairman and Co-founder, Coursera.

The IEEE specifically requires this format in author lists of articles submitted to IEEE journals. The [instructions for formatting articles](https://www.ieee.org/documents/transactions_journals.pdf) list the following sample authors:

> First A. Author, Fellow, IEEE, Second B. Author, and Third C. Author, Jr., Member, IEEE

Answer (score -2):

Is this person a Fellow? [Link](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fellow)(countable noun
A fellow of an academic or professional association is someone who is a specially elected member of it, usually because of their work or achievements or as a mark of honour.

So I'd think,  "Sinno Jialin Pan and Qiang Yang, Fellow IEEE " , would be more correct -- by moving the comma.

On Edit: Thanks to verbose, the title is in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, i googled it up, it says "He was elevated to IEEE Fellow (2009 - )."

Comment: @Tomek -- I was wondering if it should not be IEEE Fellow, and not Fellow IEEE. I will edit.

Comment: Probably someone made mistake while translating from other language

Comment: @Tomek I was not a Fellow and nor did I know any  where I went to school, other than Research Fellows and I wasn't anywhere near that sort of academic. So I honestly can't say how they are addressed in different places. I was in Canada. What is the rule in Oxford or the Sorbonne or Universidade de São Paulo? I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, @Verbose. I edited my post to fix it and it's wrong!